# How to generate such an image?

Tags: graphics

[image: picture]

Inspired by [this](http://www.twipu.com/NovickProf/tweet/1133211527367073792), I'm using `Graphics` to generate such a image, but it return

[image: new picture]

I want every disk to be the same color. How to modify to make it work? Using image related functions is OK, `DiskMatrix` etc.

```
Graphics[Table[{{Opacity[0.5],White,Disk[{0,0},11.25]},
  {RGBColor[{136,28,255}/255],Disk[{x,y},0.25]}},{x,-15,15},{y,-15,15}],
     Background->Yellow, PlotRangePadding->None]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the large disk outside `Table` and use `Opacity[1]`:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[1], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 11.25], 
  Table[{{RGBColor[{136, 28, 255}/255], Disk[{x, y}, 0.25]}},
    {x, -15,  15}, {y, -15, 15}]}, 
   Background -> Yellow, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: I want every disk to be the same color.

Comment: @mathe, please see the updated version.